# Using JDE in Emacs, I would like something like Eclipse's run configurations

Tags: eclipse, emacs, jde

I'm using JDE for writing a larger project. Coming from Eclipse, i miss the run configurations. Basically, there are several different classes in the project that i would like to launch. Some of them are applets, some of the are regular classes with a main method. I would also like to be able to specify different run time arguments to them.

Basically, something like this:

```
run_config_1
  applet: false
  main class: package1.subpackage1.ClassX
  arguments: arg1 arg2

run_config_2
  applet: true
  main class: package1.subpackage1.AppletClassX
  arguments:

etc ...
```

Then I could switch configuration on the fly, testing different parts of the project. So is there something like this for JDE? Or do I have to write it myself? If that is the case, I would like some pointers on the general direction I should take.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at what is already available in JDE? E.g. "Running Java Applications" at http://jdee.sunsite.dk/jdedoc/html/jde-ug/jde-ug.html ?

Answer (score 0):

you can switch configrations indeed: use the "project files" for this. in a project file your current JDE settings can be recorded. you can set the arguments for java compile and run to your liking. start with `jde-create-new-project`. you need to set up new directories for each configuration (=project file).

here a generated sample project file

```
(jde-project-file-version "1.0")
(jde-set-variables
 '(jde-project-name "mysample")
 '(jde-run-option-application-args (quote ("-v" "mydir")))
 '(jde-run-read-app-args t))
```